# How to remove gap between Header navigation bar and slider revolution in wordpress website

Tags: css

How to remove the gap between the Header navigation bar and slider revolution in WordPress website.

Comment: Please share any code snippet, screenshot or link where you deploy your code. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The gap between the header navigation bar and slider revolution is due to the vote for us image wrapper. Unless you set its **`position`** to **`absolute`** then you can get rid of the gap.

Try to add this in your custom CSS:

```
<style>
  .wpb_raw_code.wpb_raw_js > .wpb_wrapper > a img{
     position:absolute;
  }
</style>
```

Comment: Above solution will overlap the **vote for us** image on **Revolution Slider**.

Comment: nothing going to change still remaining as same after adding this code to my Customizing Additional CSS. If it's okay this image overlapping my slider are

Comment: @SandunGunawardana add it in the global custom css , when you go to customization

Comment: @fmsthird, on my website having only  Additional CSS area only. I added to that area. but it's not working

Comment: how about adding it directly to your theme's style.css file

Comment: @fmsthird, I tried styles.css also not going to change. I want like this way to be on my website https://ibb.co/vqXn8cW.

 I need to add one hyperlinked image right corner to my WordPress website between the main navigation bar and slider revolution area. When someone scrolling down with the navigation bar and that image has to the visible the entire website every page. Any CSS cord for this matter

Comment: yeah using code above. you can put it in the heade and wrap it with style tag wait i will update answer

Comment: @SandunGunawardana try updated answer but I hope it wont break any other elements

Comment: @SandunGunawardana the updated one should work

Comment: @fmsthird, the code will be working but my theme some elements are totally changed. and mobile compatible version also mess up. visit and see the above web link. I added to this code to the header.php file

Comment: @SandunGunawardana try updated code, `.wpb_raw_code.wpb_raw_js > .wpb_wrapper > a img{
     position:absolute;
  }`

Comment: @fmsthird, how can I do it? If I gave you my backend can you help me to resolve this Please

Comment: I can see you did it already, only you need to change code with the updated one in my answer

Comment: @fmsthird, Hopefully, done. great job. Thanks a lot

Comment: Great! kindly upvote answer and accept if it helps you:)

Answer (score 0):

The issue is not related to **Revolution Slider** it's because of your **vote for us** image. This image contain Extra `Height`, `Width` and `Margin`.

[image]

Remove **Margin**, change `height="150"` to `height="90"` and `width="150"` to `width="90"`.

[image]

Comment: @siddiqui, I tried removing Margin, change height="150" to height="90" and width="150" to width="90" then logo going to be not visible